# How to find out which function called my widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, showdialog, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

Is there any way to find out which function between `showDialog()` and `showModalBottomSheet()` called my widget? I want to change its property based on which function is called.

this is my button code:

```
AppButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      useSafeArea: true,
      enableDrag: true,
      context: context,
      isDismissible: true,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context) => const ModalsTeamManagement(),
    );
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const ModalsTeamManagement();
      },
    );
  },
  child: const Text('Team Management'),
);
```

Comment: yes, there are some trick you can do but I cant see any showDialog or showModalBottomSheet  on your snippet.

Comment: I edited my code, apologies for the confusion

Comment: Just pass some meaningful flag.  Anything more clever will be fragile.

Answer (score 0):

From your current snippet it will show both but, you may use `awai` to confirm closing the dialog.

```dart
//you can place theses on state class 
bool wasDialog = false;
bool wasModalBottomSheet = false;
  
//use case
AppButton(
  onPressed: () async {
   wasModalBottomSheet =true; // it will  always show showModalBottomSheet
   await showModalBottomSheet(...);
   if (context.mounted) {
    wasDialog = true;
    await showDialog(...);
    }
  },
  child: const Text('Team Management'),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i can handle that with 1 bool in my ModalsTeamManagement class but i want to know is there any other method like we find widget from context but for functions ? i used both of them for UI preview

Comment: sorry I am not aware of this, maybe you can describe what exactly you are trying to archive,  in real life scenario, I return bool from `showModalBottomSheet` that will be used to show showDialog based on result.